# How to keep last modified date of directories unchanged when files in directory change?

Tags: folders, settings

I am syncing files between macOS and a remote Ubuntu server.

On Ubuntu, the date of last modification of a directory doesn't change when I store, modify or delete a file inside this directory. This behavior makes sense to me, because it's the directory's content, not the directory itself, that has changed.

On macOS this behavior is different (and seems irrational to me): Although the directory itself stays unchanged, its "last modified" date gets changed every time when something inside this directory gets changed.

So, when I create a directory on macOS and sync it to Ubuntu, everything is fine: both have the same date. But when I move files in one of the directories, and sync those files, the directories date on Ubuntu keeps its old value, but the date on the corresponding directory on macOS will be changed, and then, because of this different date, my sync-programm shows differences where in fact no differences are.

Is there a setting in macOS, that induces my iMac's directories to behave like their counterparts on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't have an answer but just a comment.

Ubuntu is the one with the broken behavior here.  If you modify the contents of a file in a directory on MacOS (or anywhere), I'd not expect the timestamp on the directory to change, within limits.  But if you add or remove entries in the directory, I would certainly expect the modify timestamp of the directory to change, because you HAVE modified it.

Comment: Additional comment to Marc's one: both folder date behaviors are plausible and have pros and cons. With a sync app working properly it shouldn't make any difference though.

Comment: @MarcWilson well if you renamed a directory would that be modifying it?

Comment: @klanomath why? is it because you think a sync app should ignore the timestamp of directories and only go by the timestamp of files that aren't directories?

Comment: @barlop If the changed "last modified" date of a folder doesn't trigger the sync app to transfer the whole content (because nothing has changed really - e.g. after moving a folder/file out and in again), but change the "last modified" date and the metadata of the folder itself, then it's no problem.

Comment: @barlop I have done no testing, but I would expect that the timestamp of the containing directory would change, not the timestamp of the directory you renamed.  Have you tested this?

Comment: @MarcWilson a) re your first comment, actually, modifying the contents of a file will cause the timestamp of the parent directory to change. (so that seems contrary to your first comment) https://pastebin.com/raw/hbQWx9kx  b) renaming/mv a file/dir won't change its timestamp but will change the timestamp of the parent. (so that agrees with your recent comment).

Comment: @barlop Both behaviors in my first comment are reasonable, neither can be said to be "correct".  For the second comment, the timestamp on the parent must change because you're writing to the parent, not the child.

Comment: @MarcWilson So when you said in your first comment "If you modify the contents of a file in a directory on MacOS (or anywhere), I'd not expect the timestamp on the directory to change,"  <-- You weren't talking of what actually happens in MacOS?  And my point is your expectation was wrong.  (And i'm not saying that  that suggested behaviour wouldn't be  reasonable)